# BigQuery Upload Encoding Error (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload some data into my BigQuery tables using HTTP post (httplib2).  My existing upload Python code has always worked until I moved to Python 3.  Now I get encoding errors on the body of the request for the same data I was uploading successfully before using Python 2.7.x.

The error happens when the HTTP client library tries to encode the body using the default HTTP encoding of ISO-8859-1.  It fails stating that it couldn't encode characters at position xxxx-yyyy.

I have heard of a Python 3 Unicode bug but don't know if it's related or not.  What should I do to get my upload working with Python 3 and the bigquery API (v2)?

Comment: I saw this was down voted.  Please provide suggestions on how to improve the question so I can get it answered, or at leas why it was down voted.

Comment: This is mostly python related I will add the tag. You can improve by adding debug code. Downvote is not mine